# FIREBASE_TOKEN deprecated in CI/CD gitlab

Tags: firebase, deployment, gitlab, cicd

I encountered a warning while deploying my web app, firebase tells me that the token is about to be deprecated and I recommend using google credentials.

[cicd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLNua.png)

Do you have any advice on how to setup the gitlab pipeline to use google credentials? I have not found a guide on this. This is my script.

[gitlab script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgw1Q.png)

At the moment I have configured a gitlab environment variable containing the token and it works (with warning).

[gitlab firebase token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVpxQ.png)

I tried setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in gitlab settings but I don't know the firebase command to use to deploy.

Answer (score 5):

I found the way to deploy from gitlab using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
This is my script:

```
image: node:14.18.0-alpine

before_script:
  - npm i -g firebase-tools
  - echo $FIARD_PRIVATE_KEY > "/private-key.json"
  - export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/private-key.json"

stages:
  - staging
  - production

deploy_staging:
  stage: staging
  when: manual
  script:
    - firebase use staging
    - firebase deploy --only hosting:ineffe-business-site-staging
    - echo "Deploying hosting staging finished!"
  only:
    - master
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging-business-ineffe.firebaseapp.com/

deploy_production:
  stage: production
  when: manual
  script:
    - firebase use default
    - firebase deploy --only hosting:ineffe-business-site-prod
    - echo "Deploying hosting production finished!"
  only:
    - master
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://business-ineffe-com.firebaseapp.com/
```

I created the environment variable on gitlab based on the environment (staging and production) and it works.
The variables contain the authentication json provided by Google.

[gitlab env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3isgZ.png)

I posted this answer if it can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar but as it is simpler I want to share with you

```yaml
firebase-deploy:
  image: node:20-alpine
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - echo $GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT > service-account.json
    - export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="service-account.json"
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
  script:
    - firebase deploy
  environment: production
```